# I missed my medical visit for my carte de sejour in france due to COVID-19. Can I still re-enter the country on my work visa?

Tags: france

I missed my medical visit for my carte de sejour in france due to COVID-19. Can I still re-enter the country on my work visa?  I recieved my visa in November. My medical appointment to receive my carte de sejour was scheduled in mid March, but since all the craziness happened with COVID i returned to the US and couldn't attend my medical appointment. Will i be allowed back into the country on my work visa, how does one go about rescheduling the medical appointment?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a mess, I don't think the law really foresees a case like this one. An [executive order](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/eli/ordonnance/2020/3/25/INTV2008127R/jo/texte) extended for three, then six months, all visas and residence permits that should have expired between March 16 and May 15. However, yours wasn't set to expire exactly and even if its validity would have been extended, you would still formally require it to be validated to have the right to be in France or [reenter the Schengen area](http://accueil-etrangers.gouv.fr/demande-de-titre-de-sejour/vous-etes-ressortissant-e-non-europeen-ne/vous-etes-ressortissant-e-de-pays-tiers-non-algerien-ne/vous-etes-arrive-e-en-france-avec-un-visa-de-long-sejour-valant-titre-de-sejour/vous-venez-d-arriver-en-france/).

There is also a procedure called “*visa de retour*” for people who are stuck abroad without their residence permit but that's not your case either as you hadn't got a residence permit yet (you had a *titre de séjour* but no *carte de séjour*). I think your best bet is to approach the consulate about your situation and hope that the police and *préfecture* will show some leniency, given this exceptional situation.

From a strict legal standpoint, the only procedure that is definitely available would be a fresh application for a new long-stay visa.